# VSTS Build variable on Pull Request

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm currently using AppCenter to Test my Xamarin app. The complete suite is being run at night. But I'm currently looking for a way to make this part of my CI builds to introduce an extra quality gate before features get merged.

However, we would need to slim down the amount of tests that need to be run otherwise this would become unmanageable. For this we can specify categories on our App Center test build step. When queued manually I'm able to specify the categories, however when we make this CI Build part of a branch policy and use a manual trigger for our build validation we are unable to specify the categories as we don't get the popup when queuing.

Any suggestions on how to adres this issue differently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems you want to **set build variables in pull requests** when you queue the build under policies.

[image]

Unfortunately, this could not be achieved by now. It will not pop up the dialog when you queue the build. There has been a related uservoice, you could vote up and follow it, TFS PM will kindly review your suggestion.

> **Allow Setting Build Variables in Pull Requests**
>
> https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/365725/allow-setting-build-variables-in-pull-requests.html

The only workaround for now is editing the build definitions and add the variable under **variables** directly, then queue again. You could clone the original build definition first.